# Tomcat: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: no cipher suites in common

Tags: ssl, tomcat8, intellij-14

I'm trying to setup a remote tomcat server for deployment in IntelliJ.

For some reason the "handshake" fails.

> 11:44:28 Error running VPS-Tomcat
>            Unable to connect to the 185.80.128.231:1099, reason:
>            java.rmi.ConnectIOException: error during JRMP connection establishment; nested exception is: 
>            javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure

I added some debug options to tomcat startup:

> Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
>   Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
>   Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
>   Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
>   Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
>   Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
>   Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
>   Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
>   Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
>   Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
>   Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
>   Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
>   Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
>   Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
>   RMI TCP Connection(16)-78.60.67.248, READ: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 207
>   *** ClientHello, TLSv1.2
>   RandomCookie:  GMT: 1431613995 bytes = { 210, 37, 184, 64, 38, 79, 199, 129, 139, 3, 89, 15, 7, 99, 193, 123, 94, 24, 149, 84, 76, 24, 210, 199, 14, 10, 32, 220 }
>   Session ID:  {}
>   Cipher Suites: [TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]
>   Compression Methods:  { 0 }
>   Extension elliptic_curves, curve names: {secp256r1, sect163k1, sect163r2, secp192r1, secp224r1, sect233k1, sect233r1, sect283k1, sect283r1, secp384r1, sect409k1, sect409r1, secp521r1, sect571k1, sect571r1, secp160k1, secp160r1, secp160r2, sect163r1, secp192k1, sect193r1, sect193r2, secp224k1, sect239k1, secp256k1}
>   Extension ec_point_formats, formats: [uncompressed]
>   Extension signature_algorithms, signature_algorithms: SHA512withECDSA, SHA512withRSA, SHA384withECDSA, SHA384withRSA, SHA256withECDSA, SHA256withRSA, SHA224withECDSA, SHA224withRSA, SHA1withECDSA, SHA1withRSA, SHA1withDSA, MD5withRSA
>   %% Initialized:  [Session-14, SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL]
>   %% Invalidated:  [Session-14, SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL]
>   RMI TCP Connection(16)-78.60.67.248, SEND TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, description = handshake_failure
>   RMI TCP Connection(16)-78.60.67.248, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 2
>   RMI TCP Connection(16)-78.60.67.248, called closeSocket()
>   RMI TCP Connection(16)-78.60.67.248, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: no cipher suites in common
>   RMI TCP Connection(16)-78.60.67.248, called close()
>   RMI TCP Connection(16)-78.60.67.248, called closeInternal(true)

I don't really understand it but I *assume* that one end is using TLS1.2 and the other TLS1.1 although I'm not even sure which is which.

So how can I configure them to both use the same version? Or make tomcat support those cipher suites?

Or does the problem lie elsewhere?

Comment: The problem is the cipher suites, just as the message says, not the version. Have you set the cipher suites at either end?

Comment: I didn't set anything by myself. On the server side they should be handled by tomcat and on my side by intellij.

Comment: HI @JustasS did you resolve this? I have same issue.. :(